# Instead of receiving the contract address i'm getting undefined(HardHat, ethers.js)

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

```js
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const currentTimestampInSeconds = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000);
  const unlockTime = currentTimestampInSeconds + 60;

  const lockedAmount = hre.ethers.parseEther("0.001");

  const lock = await hre.ethers.deployContract("Lock", [unlockTime], {
    value: lockedAmount,
  });

  const Token = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Token");
  const token = await Token.deploy();

  await token.deploymentTransaction().wait(1);
  console.log(`Token Deployed to: ${token.value}`);

  console.log(
    `Lock with ${ethers.formatEther(
      lockedAmount
    )}ETH and unlock timestamp ${unlockTime} deployed to ${lock.target}`
  );
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

**output**:
Token Deployed to: undefined
Lock with 0.001ETH and unlock timestamp 1697469516 deployed to 0x9E545E3C0baAB3E08CdfD552C960A1050f373042
Done in 3.80s.

The issue being the token's address is set to undefined not sure why, can someone help me out?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with answering your own question - however the problem you've outlined is either due to not correctly reading the documentation or a typo. As such it's very unlikely to help other and is just noise which should be deleted.

Answer (score -2):

so the solution for this was:

change this line

```js
  console.log(`Token Deployed to: ${token.value}`);
```

to:

```js
  console.log(`Token Deployed to: ${token.target}`);
```

works well, i'm using ethers v6